# fact abt ruby time

Tags: ruby

can anyone tell me why Time.at(0) in ruby gives 1970-01-01 05:30:00 +530 . any specific reason why it gives this date and time

Answer (score 2):

My crystal ball tells me you are in India. India's time zone is UTC+5:30. The time 0 is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, which was 1970-01-01 00:05:30 local time in India.

On my system:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.at(0)
=> Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 +1200 1970
```

Comment: Why is the time zone listed as `+530` instead of `+5:30` ?

Answer (score 1):

That time is the Unix Epoch - from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch):

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system
>   for describing points in time, defined
>   as the number of seconds elapsed since
>   midnight proleptic Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC) of January 1,
>   1970, not counting leap seconds. It is
>   used widely, not only in Unix-like
>   operating systems, but also in many
>   other computing systems and file
>   formats. It is neither a linear
>   representation of time nor a true
>   representation of UTC (though it is
>   frequently mistaken for both), as it
>   cannot represent standard UTC leap
>   seconds (e.g. December 31, 1998
>   23:59:60), although otherwise the
>   times it represents are UTC. Unix time
>   may be checked on some Unix systems by
>   typing date +%s on the command line.

Essentially Unix systems count all times as number of seconds from 00:00 UTC on 1970-01-01.